# ternary operator for ngmodel if value is undefined

Tags: angular

I have an angular component used in 2 different components. I am binding the input value to ngModel but I need no make a difference for ngModel binding, when to use Invite and when to use InviteAdmin.

```
<input [disabled]="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="invite.mail.value">
```

I have tried with ternary operator when 
For the first one I have a response with a model class like this

```
[ngModel]="invite.mail.value ? invite.mail.value : invite.mail"
```

but I get syntax error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

How can I do this?

Bellow are my 2 models

```
interface Invite {
  id: string;
  dep: string;
  stand: string;
  mail: string;
}
```

and in the second component the response is an object like this

```
class ValueError {
  value: string;
  error?: string;

  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.error = null;
  }
}
export class InviteAdmin{
  id: ValueError;
  dep: ValueError;
  stand: ValueError;
  mail: ValueError;

  constructor() {
    this.id= new ValueError();
    this.dep= new ValueError();
    this.stand= new ValueError();
    this.mail= new ValueError();
  }
}
```

Comment: "but I get syntax error". what is the error? (:

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

Comment: I don't get it fully. What is the type of `invite`? Is it an instance of `Invite`? In this case, `invite.mail.value` results in a Compile error, because `invite.mail` is supposed to be a string.

Comment: also, do you have ivy enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the excerpt

```
[ngModel]="invite.mail.value ? invite.mail.value : invite.mail"
```

I'm sure it should work. If you could provide stackblitz with repro, we would be able to help. Most likely the error not in this place, but nearby.

btw, shorter version of the same code

```
[ngModel]="invite.mail.value || invite.mail"
```